# Playwright throws aPIRequestContext.get: Request context disposed

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, automated-tests, playwright

I have a code that needs to loop the json file. However it throws this error:

```
aPIRequestContext.get: Request context disposed.
```

And I have no idea why.
Here's how I implemented it:
[image]

When I try to put the block of code outside the base.loopJsonData, it works... but not when inside. I tried to print the json details and I'm getting an output but not when I'm using request.get()

Here's the **loopJsonData**:

```
public loopJsonData(json, data, callback) {
        const inputData = this.loadJSONData(json, data);
        inputData.forEach((val, i) => {
            ((item, index) => {
                callback(item, index, inputData);
            })(val, i);
        });
    }
```

Here's the **loadJSONData**:

```
public loadJSONData(path: string, testData: string) {
        let jsonPath;

        this.contentPath = join(process.cwd(), path);
        this.contentPath = normalizer.normalize(this.contentPath);
        this.contentPath = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this.contentPath, "utf8"));
        jsonPath = this.contentPath;
        return jsonPath[testData];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loopJsonData` takes async function but doesn't `await` it inside (just calls it synchronously for each data item `inputData.forEach((val, i) => {`). With such approach inner `request.get()` will run after the test method finishes and it will race with tear down logic which disposes the `request` (essentially you call `request.get()` after `request.dispose()` has been called).

To fix this you should ensure that all async callbacks are waited for, something like this:

```js
async loopJsonData(json, data, callback) {
    const inputData = this.loadJSONData(json, data);
    const promises = [];
    inputData.forEach((val, i) => {
        promises.push(callback(val, i, inputData));
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript world and learned a lot from this and the promises. I'm really grateful for your explanation!